# How can I find animal sound database for my needs?

Tags: audio

I have developed an **MFCC** algorithm and want to **cluster** same species of **animal sounds** with my application. I searched on internet and collected some animal sounds. My each sound files should be including just one animal's voice. It should be some kind of farm animals. I tried to collect all the small good sounds from internet and I will append each of animal's sounds and process them. I mean I will have 3 cat sounds and they will be one, I have 4 dog sounds they will be one too.

However I couldn't find enough good sound for my project (I should find 2-3 minutes sound records for each animal and each animal species for example cat, should include different cats' sounds )

How can I find animal sound database for my needs?

Comment: I assume this software was meant to identify which animal it is from a sound recording? Was the project successful?

Comment: It was for clustering the animal sound, not classifying and become successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.findsounds.com/types.html

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.animal-sounds.org/farm-animal-sounds.html) may be a starting point, even if sounds are not 2 minutes long. 
ps. 2 minutes of a cow?? It would seems an eternity! :)

Comment: There may be some cow voices 30 seconds long and there can be 4 different cows. I can use different animals within same species.